Google Promotion Tab / Email Annotations code HTML code markup doesnt work
I am contacting you because I am testing sending emails that contain email annotations with the aim of displaying promotional information associated with the email when users go to the Gmail Promotion tab to view said email. But these tests are failing.
I create an email in the email marketing tool, added the corresponding code so that there are changes in the Gmail interface once the user receives the email, but they are not visible. It would appear that the Gmail interface does not accept the code.
I would need to know what formats you still support, the HTML language (putting a div in the head) apparently works well, but we can't get all the options that email annotations have to be displayed (images, carousel, etc.) .
Using HTML the code seems to work but not as required.
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/DiscountOffer">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Activa tu oferta">
<meta itemprop="discountCode" content="BBVA2023">
<meta itemprop="availabilityStarts" content="2024-01-13T08:11:06-08:00">
<meta itemprop="availabilityEnds" content="2025-01-31T08:11:06-23:00">
</div>

On the other hand, if we choose the JSON-LD language, we have not obtained any combination that displays the Email Annotation in the Gmail Promotion tab.
Since email annotations is a functionality that sits outside of Google's corporate package, could you please give us a Google technical contact that we can talk to about this topic? It is causing us a significant blockage since Business wants to make use of this functionality.
I am expecting to see a Deal Annotation
<div ="" itemtype="http://schema.org/DiscountOffer">
<meta ="description" content="Activa tu oferta">
<meta ="discountCode" content="BBVA2023">
<meta ="availabilityStarts" content="2024-01-13T08:11:06-08:00">
<meta ="availabilityEnds" content="2025-01-31T08:11:06-23:00">
</div>

I'm expecting a Deal Offer views on the promotion tabs at gmail.
